# wrong server time in backend of TYPO3 9.5

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

2 servers, DEV and life. Both identical php 7.4 installation with same php.ini (I compared the php.info output). Same version of TYPO3 (via composer and GIT, last TYPO3 9.5.23).

DEV shows in the scheduler this time:
Current server time is 26-11-20 11:47 CET (Europe/Berlin, GMT +01:00).

Life shows:
Current server time is 26-11-20 12:46 CEST (Europe/Berlin, GMT +02:00).

Both does have the entry [SYS][phpTimeZone] = Europe/Berlin in LocalConfiguration.php.

It is obvious that the life server shows UTC instead of the correct time zone despite the entry [SYS][phpTimeZone] = Europe/Berlin.

I am lost.

Is there an other entry i the system configuration - or on any other place - which is able to alter the server time of TYPO3?

Thanks!

Comment: One server misses the end of daylight-saving-time there are: `CET` and `CEST`

Comment: Call the hoster to set the "Sommerzeit" correctly. :)